# Page need to be refresh to display my new content in Angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2, push

I have a component in order to posts reviews in my app but I need to refresh my page to display a new review. I just have a blank box before refresh (cf screenshot)
FYI : I have one component template to get reviews, and one other bundle for post a review.
I don't understand what i'm doing wrong... ?

[image]

### My service

```
userAddReview(params) {
    console.log('sending request');
        return this.authHttp.post(this.wpApiURL + '/users-reviews/reviews',params)
        .map(
            res => {
                let newReview = res.json();
                this.reviews.push(newReview);
                console.log(this.reviews);
                return newReview;
            }
        );
}
```

### My review form component

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WpService, AuthService } from '../../services/index';
import { ProfilePage } from '../../pages/profile/profile';
import { ReviewList } from '../reviewList/reviewList.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'review-form',
    templateUrl: './reviewForm.html'
})

export class ReviewFormComponent {

    @Input() postId: number;
    @Input() review: any;
    @Input() isEditMode: boolean;
    @Output() isEditModeChange = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() reviewChange = new EventEmitter();
    jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
    statusMessage = '';
    isEditing: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        private wp: WpService, 
        private auth: AuthService, 
        private nav: NavController,
        ) { 
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.review.post = this.postId;
        this.review.author = this.wp.getCurrentAuthorId();
        if (this.review.author === null) {
            this.review.author = 0
            console.log('user_id', this.review.author)
        }
    }

    onCancel() {
        this.reviewChange.emit({
            content: {rendered: ''},
            author: null,
            post: this.postId
        }); 
        this.isEditing = false;
        this.isEditModeChange.emit(false);
        this.statusMessage = '';
        return false;
    }

    showPanel() {
        return (this.isEditing) || this.isEditMode;
    }

    submitReview(form) {
        console.log(this.review, form);
        let params = new URLSearchParams;
        params.append('id', this.postId.toString());
        params.append('user_id', (this.review.author).toString());
        params.append('name', this.review.rating_name);
        params.append('email', this.review.rating_user_email);
        params.append('title', this.review.rating_title);
        params.append('description', this.review.rating_comment);
        params.append('rating', this.review.rating_score);
        console.log(params);
        this.wp.userAddReview(params)
            .subscribe(
                newReview => {
                    this.statusMessage = "Review added successfully!";
                    //clear form
                    form.reset();
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error._body);
                    this.statusMessage = error._body;
                }
        );
    }
}
```

### My review form template

```
<form name="reviewForm" #reviewForm="ngForm" novalidate *ngIf="showPanel()">
    <div *ngIf="!reviewText.valid && (reviewText.dirty || reviewText.touched)" class="alert alert-danger padding">review is required</div>

    <div class="padding">{{statusMessage}}</div>
    <ion-item *ngIf="!auth.authenticated()">
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="review.rating_name" #reviewUsername="ngModel" name="reviewUsername" placeholder="enter your name here..." required></ion-input>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="review.rating_user_email" #reviewUserEmail="ngModel" name="reviewUserEmail" placeholder="enter your email here..." required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-range min="0" max="10" step="1" snaps="true" [(ngModel)]="review.rating_score" #reviewScore="ngModel" name="reviewScore">
            <ion-label range-left>0</ion-label>
            <ion-label range-right>10</ion-label>
        </ion-range>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="review.rating_title" #reviewTitle="ngModel" name="reviewTitle" placeholder="enter your review title..." required></ion-input>
    <ion-textarea
        [(ngModel)]="review.rating_comment"
        #reviewText="ngModel"
        name="reviewText"
        type="text"
        rows="2"
        placeholder="enter your review..."
        required
        >
    </ion-textarea>

    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col *ngIf="!isEditMode"><button ion-button block (click)="submitReview(reviewForm)" [disabled]="!reviewForm.valid">Add</button></ion-col>
            <ion-col *ngIf="isEditMode"><button ion-button block (click)="updateReview(reviewForm)" [disabled]="!reviewForm.valid">Update</button></ion-col>
            <ion-col width-33><button ion-button block (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

</form>

<p *ngIf="!showPanel()" (click)="isEditing = true;">Add Review</p>
```

### My reviews list component

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { AlertController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SITE_URL, WpService } from '../../services/index';

@Component({
    selector: 'reviews-list',
    templateUrl: './reviewsList.html'
})

export class ReviewsListComponent {

    @Input() postId: number;
    wpApiURL: string = SITE_URL + '/wp-json/wp/v2';
    reviews: any = [];
    authorId = null;

    constructor(
        private http: Http, 
        private wp: WpService,
        private alertCtrl: AlertController,
        private toastCtrl: ToastController
        ) {
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        // Load reviews
        this.loadReviews(this.postId);
    }

    loadReviews(postId) {
        this.wp.getReviewsByPostId({reviews: postId}).subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.reviews = data;
            },
            error => {}            
        );
    }
}
```

### My reviews list template

```
<h3>Reviews</h3>
<div *ngIf="reviews.length > 0">
    <ion-card *ngFor="let review of reviews">
        <ion-item>
            <h2>{{review.rating_user_name}}</h2>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-card-content [innerHTML]="review.rating_score"></ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-content [innerHTML]="review.rating_title"></ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-content [innerHTML]="review.rating_comment"></ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</div>

<div *ngIf="reviews.length === 0">
        No review yet.
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your view template?  The only local variable you're updating in your observable subsrciption is this.statusMessage, so if you're expecting a review collection to be updated you'll need to update it's value in your subscription...

Comment: Yes, I updated my post

Comment: Where is `this.reviews` variable in your component ?

Comment: @YounesM my thoughts exactly, it doesn't seem that your component could typescript compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not updating your reviews collection in your subscription.

you need to do somethign like this:

```
 this.wp.userAddReview(params)
        .subscribe(
            newReview => {
                this.statusMessage = "Review added successfully!";
                this.reviews.push(newReview); //add the new review to the local collection
                //clear form
                form.reset();
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error._body);
                this.statusMessage = error._body;
            }
    );
```

EDIT--
In your component it doesn't appear you have a reviews collection in the component.  A typical pattern we use for calling a service from a component is to susbcribe to an observable defined in a service class from your component.  In the subscribe promise, map the emitted value to a local component variable, and then use that local component variable in your view template.

So in your example you're missing a 'reviews' component variable which would be populated in your component from the value emitted from the subscription.

Designing your interactions in this way decreasing the coupling between the service and your view template.

Comment: Thought of the same thing but why does a "blank box" appear if nothing was pushed ?

Comment: @christophebazin can you post your full component code?  It looks like you defined reviews in your service instead of your component, but are referencing reviews as if it were a member of your component in your view template.

Comment: Well, I'm not the one who asked about it, bu i'm sure @christophebazin will.

Comment: Yes, I just did it !

Comment: @cobolstinks I'm going back... In fact my problem is not resolved. Despite of trying your solution.
So... I have another file with my reviews list, I think the problem is here and not in my form component. After all, it's my list who i need to refresh after a post (and I after a post I see a blank box in the bottom in without my data, after a refresh it's ok...). I updated my first post with my list component and template.

Comment: Your ReviewListComonent looks fine to me.  Are you saying the first time you load your view the review list is empty, but if you refresh the page it is populated?  Are your http requests to your service coming back as you are expecting?  Have you checked them in your brower's dev tools?

Comment: @cobolstinks On the loading page, all my reviews are displaying. But when i post one review, I have a blank box at the place of my datas.